# Is there a better way to have deep null point check while reading the below arrayNode?

Tags: java

I'm doing a null pointer check and would like to know if there is any better way in java 8 other than optional feature

```
if (cake != null && cake.frosting != null && cake.frosting.berries != null) {
//Do something
}
```

I'm looking if there is any in-line null pointer check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null check in Java 8 Elvis operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529091/null-check-in-java-8-elvis-operator) , where the answer from Brian Goetz pretty much rules out the existance of an inline null safe operator in Java, now or in the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

The Elvis operator is what you would want, but it's not part of the Java language. In Groovy you would simply do `cake?.frosting?.berries`. As you  said, you could use Optional `if(Optional.ofNullable(cake).map(c -> c.getFosting()).map(f -> f.getBerries()).isPresent())` but that IMHO is quite horrible and not the intended use for Optional. Your if statement, as you wrote it, is simple and easy to read.

Comment: And if he uses methods instead of public fields, he can use method references too

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like

```
try{
    cake.frosting.berries.toString();
}catch(NullPointerException npe){
    return;
}
//do something
```

Comment: I think I heard an engineer shrieking somewhere

Comment: To expand: you should never catch runtime exceptions (IOOBE, NPE, etc) like this, they're largely indicative of a developer error and add cost to your code if you happen to actually have a null in that chain. _Maybe_ if you never expected them to be null outside of an extreme situation, but even then...